# What was the beta password for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, private-beta

A comment on the blog entry *[Stack Overflow Private Beta Begins](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-private-beta-begins/)* (2008) says the password for Stack Overflow is "nostalgic". I'm curious (for history's sake), what was the password?

Comment: I don't know what it _was_, but sources say you can use `flux+capacitor` if you intend to go back in time to participate. The engine is extremely [considerate](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/03/making-considerate-software.html), even to time travelers. I'm going to open this again, as I feel that questions about SO's origins, however _meta_ they may be, are on topic here if not a duplicate of another. It's not like we don't have a few relics from our past enshrined here, and this is in fact an artifact we don't have.

Comment: @Tim Post: BELONGS ON USERVOICE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Please read this first. Seriously:

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-private-beta-begins/

> The beta site is at:

> http://beta.stackoverflow.com/

> Login is your email address, and the password is "falkensmaze" without the quotes.

> (note that these credentials aren't an actual account on Stack Overflow; they only exist to prevent anonymous users from seeing the site during the beta)

> Jeff

The password is a reference to the movie WarGames... For a long time, another reference to that movie was a fixture of Stack Overflow, but has since departed.

Comment: Gah! I still have this in 1Password and, when I saw it recently, I honestly thought I might be in possession of an original account *in mint condition*. Imagine what that could be worth on eBay...